# Better way to load fk without navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, navigation, entity-framework-core

I have two classes `User` and `UserDesign` which are on *one to one* relation.
`User` has informations about the user and `UserDesign` has informations about the color preference of the user.

`UserDesign` has the navigation property to `User` but `User` does not have this navigation property. Because a user can live without design (in an other project for exemple) and `User` and `UserDesign` are **not on the same assembly**.

Currently I fetch the informations like that :

```cs
_context.UserDesigns.Include(ud => ud.User)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.OtherRelations)
    .Include(ud => ud.User)
    .ThenInclude(u => u.OtherRelations2)
        .ThenInclude(or2 => or2.OtherRelations)
```

What i'd like it to do :

```cs
_context.Users.Include("UserDesign")
    .Include(u => u.OtherRelations)
    .Include(u => u.OtherRelations2)
        .ThenInclude(or2 => or2.OtherRelations)
```

which is I think more cleaner and more understandable because it's the User which is the goal of the request and not the UserDesign.

So it's not a technical problem, more a way of thinking problem ^^

Of course if there is a way to achieve my request, I don't know where I could find the informations about the UserDesign because I still not have the navigation property in the `User` class

## Edited

An other issue with this modelisation is that, if I have an other Entity which is in someway similar to UserDesign, let says UserPicture, I would fetch the informations about the User, UserDesign, and UserPicture in one query. If I was writing the raw query in SQL I could achieve that. But in the User class I don't have this navigations property so I can't achieve it with EF Core.

So my question is how can I achieve that without modifying my User class properly ? Have I to create an entity with all the relations or is there an other solution ?

Comment: Does your code work as-is? Are you hitting getting errors? If so, what are they? I see your `Currently what I'm doing` and `What I'd like to do` sections. However, you do not explain why either do not work apart from `more cleaner and understandable`.

Comment: `Include` is used to populate navigation properties. Since the entity in question ("the goal of the request") has no navigation property to be populated, what exactly are you trying to achieve with `Include`?

Comment: My code (which looks like the first snippet) works as-is yes. I may not have well explain the problem. If i have two entities in relation with my user, for exemple the color he likes and the photo he has, I would like to get in one request all the entity in relation with the user even if the user does not have the navigation property, If I was writing the query on my own I could make the join and get back all the related informations about the user in one query. So my question is, how can I achieve that in EF Core based on my clean models

Comment: The point is, your `User` model has no `UserDesign` (or `UserPicture`) property, so it can't be used to return that information. You need to create another class (DTO, ViewModel etc.) which has all these properties (a tuple of `User`, `UserDesign`, `UserPicture` etc.) and populate it with LINQ `Select` in a similar way you would do it in SQL.

Comment: Yes it mays solve the problem but which entry point do I have to use in order to populate this tuple ? I have to create a new DbSet ? But that will create a new table ? Do you have an idea of the code I could use ?

Comment: I understand that you have a general `User` class that is used in several projects (and probably databases). I think you should create `User` subtypes in each assembly that refers to `User` so you can map the subtypes in the appropriate context and extend the derived classes with all required navigation properties.

Comment: I think this solution will not work because each subtypes which refers to `User` and the derived classes of `User` will not be of type `User` so the navigation property will not works.
Finally I implement the solution of @IvanStoev by creating a class `UserInfos` which has navigation property to `User`, `UserDesign` and `UserPicture`. That solution is not perfect but it still works and even if the join is bigger (4 tables instead of 3), it's acceptable in this project